# QueryDSL Java Mongo SubQuery matching all condition returns incorrect result

Tags: java, mongodb, querydsl

I have a Person object having List

Using queryDSL, I want to fetch all persons having address state=MH,city=MU && state=KL,city=CO.

For this I have used below code,

```
QPerson qPerson = new QPerson("person");

QAddress address = qPerson.address.any();

BooleanExpression state1 = address.state.eq("MH");
BooleanExpression city1= address.city.eq("MU");
BooleanExpression expression1 = state1.and(city1);


BooleanExpression state2 = address.state.eq("KL");
BooleanExpression city2= address.city.eq("CO");
BooleanExpression expression2 = state2.and(city2);

BooleanExpression expression = expression1.and(expression2);

this.personRepository.findAll(expression);
```

The code does not returns me correct data, when I try to run this.

=============

After your suggestion @Harshit, I changed the code with SpringDataMongoDBQuery for elemMatch.

Code here is below, is does not gives me correct result:

```
QAddress qAddress = QAddress.address;

BooleanExpression state1 = qAddress.state.eq("MH");
BooleanExpression city1 = qAddress.city.eq("MU");
BooleanExpression first = state1.and(city1);

BooleanExpression state2 = qAddress.state.eq("KL");
BooleanExpression city2 = qAddress.city.eq("CO");

BooleanExpression second = state2.and(city2);

List<Person> fetch = new SpringDataMongodbQuery<>(mongoTemplate, Person.class)
  .where()
  .anyEmbedded(qPerson.addresses, qAddress)
  .on(first, second)
  .fetch();
```

Please help with this.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, mongo query, and results you are expecting?

Comment: If I execute the script in Mongo shell, it looks similar to this: 
    db.getCollection('persons').find({
 "addresses": {$all: [{$elemMatch: {"state": "MH", "city": "MU""}},{$elemMatch: {"state": "KL", "city": "CO"}}]}})

Comment: For elemMatch query, you need to use SpringDataMongodbQuery. see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1524#issuecomment-752649364

Comment: @Harshit : I have updated the code with SpringDataMongodbQuery. Please check

Comment: It's not giving correct results because your mongo shell query is using ```$all``` operator, which is not yet supported in Querydsl. You need to change your query.

Comment: Okay. Could you help me with forming the QueryDSL query @Harshit

Comment: ```$all``` is not supported in QueryDSL yet, so either you need to query using MongoDB Criteria or change mongo shell query, which contains only operators supported in QueryDSL.